# ArcGIS Python syntax error using nested if else

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, error-000989

I am trying to use the field calculator in ArcMap 10.2 to fill an empty field based on the contents of two exiting fields usint this python script in the Pre-Logic Script Code.

```
def myfunc(legend,biltype):
    if(legend == '0000 Manmade surface or step'):
        return 'Manmade surface or step'
    elif(legend == '0000 Multiple surface (garden)'):   
        return 'Garden'
    elif(legend == '0000 Natural surface'): 
        return 'Natural Surface'
    elif(legend == '0000 Path'):    
        return 'Path'
    elif(legend == '0000 Railway'): 
        return 'Railway'
    elif(legend == '0000 Road'):    
        return 'Road'
    elif(legend == '0000 Road traffic calming'):    
        return 'Road Traffic Calming'
    elif(legend == '0000 Structure'):   
        return 'Structure'
    elif(legend == '0000 Track'):   
        return 'Track'
    elif(legend == '0000 Unclassified (or broken)'):    
        return 'Unclassified (or broken)'
    elif(legend == '0000 Unknown surface'): 
        return 'Unknown Surface'
    elif(legend == '0321 Archway'): 
        return 'Archway'
    elif(legend == '0323 Glasshouse'):  
        return 'Glasshouse'
    elif(legend == '0377 Boulders'):    
        return 'Boulders'
    elif(legend == '0379 Coniferous trees'):    
        return 'Coniferous Trees'
    elif(legend == '0380 Coniferous - scattered'):  
        return 'Coniferous - scattered'
    elif(legend == '0382 Marsh reeds or saltmarsh'):    
        return 'Marsh reeds or saltmarsh'
    elif(legend == '0384 Nonconiferous trees'): 
        return 'Nonconiferous trees'
    elif(legend == '0385 Nonconiferous - scattered'):   
        return 'Nonconiferous - scattered'
    elif(legend == '0386 Orchard'): 
        return 'Orchard'
    elif(legend == '0390 Rough grassland'): 
        return 'Rough grassland'
    elif(legend == '0392 Scrub'):   
        return 'Scrub'
    elif(legend == '0395 Upper level communication'):   
        return 'Upper level communication'
    elif(legend == '0400 Inland water'):    
        return 'Inland water'
    elif(legend == '0321 Building'):
        if(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Education'):
            return 'Education'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Emergency and Rescue Service'):
            return 'Emergency Services'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Retail'):
            return 'Retail'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Residential'):
            return 'Residential'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Industrial'):
            return 'Industrial'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Hotels'):
            return 'Hotels'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Community Services'):
            return 'Community Services'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Medical'):
            return 'Medical'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Leisure'):
            return 'Leisure'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Offices'):
            return 'Offices'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Utilities'):
            return 'Utilities'
        else:
            return 'Building - Other'
    else:
        return 'error'
```

and then setting the field to equal

```
myfunc( !LEGEND!, !blpu_class!)
```

Where LEGEND, and blpu_class as the two field with the source data.

When I run the field calculator I get an 000989 Python syntax error:parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 51)

This is the start of the nested if, but I can't work out what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine but you are missing a right parenthesis for each line of code in the nested if part:

```
if(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Education')):
            return 'Education'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Emergency and Rescue Service')):
            return 'Emergency Services'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Retail')):
            return 'Retail'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Residential')):
            return 'Residential'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Industrial')):
            return 'Industrial'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Hotels')):
            return 'Hotels'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Community Services')):
            return 'Community Services'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Medical')):
            return 'Medical'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Leisure')):
            return 'Leisure'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Offices')):
            return 'Offices'
        elif(biltype.startswith('Commercial, Utilities')):
            return 'Utilities'
```